# How to print table of contents of a pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf kinda-book file which has a table of contents as metadata in file but they are not listed on any page of the document. I want to print the file with table of contents, or print the table of contents separately. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pdftk` can dump out the "bookmarks" with, e.g., `pdftk file.pdf dump_data_utf8`; you'll get a bunch of Bookmark* entries buried in the rest of the metadata. `grep` can give just them:

```
$ pdftk whatever.pdf dump_data_utf8 | grep ^Bookmark
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Cover
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 1
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Agenda
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 2
```

The "level" is the indentation level (so a level 2 is indented from a level 1). You can format that into whatever format you want for printing.

Here is a Perl script to print it in LaTeX format, which can then be fed to e.g., `pdflatex` to get a PDF file (which you could even use pdftk to prepend to your original PDF). Note this is also available at https://gitlab.com/derobert/random-toys/blob/master/pdf/pdftoc-to-latex (which is a good place to send pull requests if you want to improve it):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.024;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);
use IPC::Run3;
use LaTeX::Encode;
use Encode qw(decode);

my @levels
    = qw(chapter section subsection subsubsection paragraph subparagraph);
my @counters;

my ($data_enc, $data);
run3 ['pdftk', $ARGV[0], 'dump_data_utf8'], undef, \$data_enc;
$data = decode('UTF-8', $data_enc, Encode::FB_CROAK);

my @latex_bm;

my $bm;
foreach (split(/\n/, $data)) {
    /^Bookmark/ or next;
    if (/^BookmarkBegin$/) {
        add_latex_bm($bm) if $bm;
        $bm = {};
    } elsif (/^BookmarkLevel: (\d+)$/a) {
        ++$counters[$1 - 1];
        $#counters = $1 - 1;
        $bm->{number} = join(q{.}, @counters);
        $bm->{level} = $1 - 1;
    } elsif (/^BookmarkTitle: (.+)$/) {
        $bm->{title} = latex_encode($1);
    } elsif (/^BookmarkPageNumber: (\d+)$/a) {
        $bm->{page} = $1;
    } else {
        die "Unknown Bookmark tag in $_\n";
    }
}
add_latex_bm($bm) if $bm;

print <<LATEX;
\\documentclass{report}
\\begin{document}
${ \join('', @latex_bm) }
\\end{document}
LATEX

exit 0;

sub add_latex_bm {
    my $bm     = shift;
    my $level  = $levels[$bm->{level}];
    my $number = $bm->{number};
    my $title  = $bm->{title};
    my $page   = $bm->{page};

    push @latex_bm, <<LINE;
\\contentsline {$level}{\\numberline {$number}$title}{$page}%
LINE
}
```

Here is how to use this script:

1. Download https://gitlab.com/derobert/random-toys/raw/master/pdf/pdftoc-to-latex?inline=false and save as **pdftoc-to-latex.pl**
2. Make it executable by running `chmod +x /path/to/pdftoc-to-latex.pl` in the terminal
3. Install **Latex::Encode** perl package. On Debian Stretch you can do so via `sudo apt install liblatex-encode-perl`. On other distros you will probably need to do something else.
4. Run the script like this: `/path/to/pdftoc-to-latex.pl /path/to/pdf/file.pdf > /path/to/where/you/want/tex/file.tex`
5. Compile the resulting tex file to pdf with your favorite LaTeX compiler (e.g., `cd /path/to/where/you/want/tex; pdflatex file.tex`)

Comment: Any you can use LaTex to take this data, and turn it into a nicely formatted, printable pdf. +1 for anyone that adds a complementary answer, on how to do this.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor code added

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to above, but quick and dirty bash script. Only depends on `pdftk` package. Assumes dirs `pdf/`, `tmp/`, and `toc/`.

```
#!/bin/bash

#usage: bash src/pdf-toc-txt.sh pdf/Del-2-200214.pdf "DEL 2"
fn="${1##*/}"
echo "processing: $fn"
rm -Rf tmp/*

#init toc file
echo "$2" > toc/$fn.txt

#pdf metadata
pdftk pdf/$fn dump_data_utf8 > tmp/$fn.txt

#build toc
cd tmp/
csplit -k $fn.txt '/^BookmarkBegin/' {*}
for i in xx*; do 
s=$(grep 'BookmarkTitle' "$i"); 
l=$(grep 'BookmarkLevel' "$i"); 
p=$(grep 'BookmarkPageNumber' "$i"); 
sl=${#s}; 
let "dl = 100 - $sl"; 
#if output toc in html format
#echo "<h$l>$s" $(printf %"$dl"s | tr " " ".") $p"</h$l>"; 
#else use text format
echo "$s" $(printf %"$dl"s | tr " " ".") "$p"; 
done | sed 's/Bookmark\(.\)\{5,10\}: //g' >> ../toc/$fn.txt

#resume
cd ..
```

Given pdf contains bookmark metadata, text output looks something like this:

```
DEL 2
 ...............................................
6 Introduktion (I) [10 sidor] ................ 4
6.1 Forskningsfrågor ......................... 5
6.1.1 Planering  av forskningsfrågor ......... 7
6.1.2 Rapportering av forskningsfrågor ....... 7
6.2 Operationalisering ....................... 8
6.2.1 Rapportering av operationalisering ..... 11
6.3 Hypoteser ................................ 12
6.3.1 Rapportering av hypoteser .............. 13
7 Metod (M) [60 sidor] ....................... 15
```